# How to avoid to do 100 queries in this case?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a simple blog in php/mysql that show in homepage latest 100 posts and for every post show the comments's number.

This is the pseudocode:

```
 Mysql query to get latest 100 posts.
 While cicle:
    Get title and body of each post.
    Mysql query to get the comments's number of the post.
```

Database structure:

```
Post:
-id
-title
-body
-date

Comments:
-id
-id_post
-id_user
-body
-date
```

Is there a way to avoid 100 queries ?

Comment: This is probably quite easy to solve using one or more `JOIN`s in your SQL statement, but we'll need much more info than what you've given. Please, at the very least, give us the MySQL statements you're currently using. Database structure would also be worthwhile, however. You should also tag this as `php`.

Comment: @dunc PHP looks irrelevant here.

Comment: You could consider writing a sql query to bring back a `summary` of the top 100 posts; this summary would include the post id, the post title, and the body of each post, as well as the comment count. That could be one query, across multiple tables via a `JOIN`, the results of which you can display any way you want.

Comment: You need to join your posts with their respective title and body and comments information

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You're most likely right, but presumably the way he's currently trying to get it to work is in PHP. Maybe there's a reason he's doing that way, so the `php` tag could be relevant.

Comment: @dunc I think the reason he's doing it that way is obvious from the existence of this question - he doesn't know any other way.

Comment: I have just added the database structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a sql query that [JOINS](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php) both of your tables together, to return all of the information you want:

```
SELECT
     p.id,
     p.title,
     p.body,
     p.date,
     COUNT(c.id)

FROM  Post p
LEFT JOIN Comments c ON p.id = C.post_id

GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.body, p.date

ORDER BY p.date DESC

LIMIT 100
```

Jeff Atwood has a [great visual guide explaining how joins work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

We are effectively selecting the top 100 posts in date order, counting the total comments (if they exist - that's why we use a LEFT JOIN as otherwise, if we use an INNER JOIN, we will ONLY return posts that have comments).

We [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) as that's how COUNT (and other aggregation functions like SUM and AVG work - we need to tell them what the rule is for counting/summing/averaging our rows.

We [ORDER BY](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlorderby.php) the post date, in DESCending order (latest first) to ensure we return posts in the order they were made.

The [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) 100 statement only returns the first 100 rows in MySql. Change it to any number you wish (a top 10, 50 etc) if you want to vary the number of posts in the summary.

The overall result is that you now have a result set that contains the post information, and the number of comments, all in one query. You can then display these results in your web application any way you see fit.

Answer (score 6):

It's a fairly straightforward query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.body. p.date, COUNT(c.id) AS comment_count
FROM Post p
LEFT JOIN Comments c ON p.id=c.id_post
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.body. p.date
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

(Please note it's untested, take it as a starting point.)

I know it's a common believe that a database is nothing but a fancy file system and `SELECT * FROM data` is all the SQL you'll ever need to know but investing some time in learning basic SQL it's absolutely worth the effort.

Comment: +1 For both the good formatting and "Read the 'full' manual" suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Just join your tables and then count the number of comments for that post.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.body, COUNT(pc.id) as comments 
FROM Post p 
LEFT JOIN Comments pc ON (p.id = pc.id_post) 
GROUP BY pc.id_post LIMIT 100
```

Hope that is what you are after.

Comment: Assuming mysql doesn't have issues with linebreaks, could you possibly add some to that query so it's readable without scrolling?

Answer (score -2):

Join your posts table with your posts-info tables, and select them at the same time

`select p.id,pi.comments from posts as p, post_info as pi where p.id == pi.id`

or something like that.

EDIT:

`select p.title,p.body,p.date,count(c.id) from post as p, comments as c where p.id == c.id_post`

I believe.

Comment: Given your database structure: Updated answer

Comment: Whilst this is a VALID approach, it's not a good one. MySQL JOINs are a better solution, as suggested by the other answers.